# How to count the total number of rows in a persisted stream table?

Tags: streaming, dolphindb

I use the function `enableTableShareAndPersistence` for stream table persistence and the parameter *cacheSize* is set to 100000, which means at most 100000 records is kept in memory.

Now I want to count the total number of rows in the stream table, including those records that have been flushed to disk.

I call exec count(*) from rwStream, but only get the number of records stored in memory of the stream table.

Answer (score 1):

Try `getPersistenceMeta(rwStream)`, you can get `totalSize` of the disk persistence.